# Appending text from all tableView cells into an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a table view which populates from an array of strings. Using UIGestureRecognizer users can reorder the cells and save the new order.

When pressing Save I need the new order of the cells to save to the array. I have tried many different techniques without success.

How can I capture all the current cell texts in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on the cell contents as your data source.  When the user reorders the cells, update your backing array to match (or a copy of it if you need to be able to revert changes).

That way, when you want to save, everything is already in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's actually how I started trying to do it but changed to the Save idea as it wasn't amending the array correctly as it went. Are you able to advise how I can have the array updated with every change?

Comment: I would capture the indexPath once they start editing the cell's position, use that indexPath to get the position in the array of the string you want to now move. Once they've finished moving the cell, grab the new indexPath, and that will tell you where to move the string to in the array, from there, just remove the string from its current location, and place it into the new location where the cell was at. This could all be done at the end of whatever method you have to handle the cell movements.

Comment: Basically what @BillL said.  It depends on what you mean by "Using UIGestureRecognizer".  The table view delegate has a `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` method that supplies the from/to information you need if you're using that mechanism for re-ordering.

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't using the correct generic table functions to reorder the cells so I removed the gesture recogniser completely and now just use the default table reorder controls and the method Phillip stated above and it works great!